# Counter for Images Displayed

Tags: java, android, arrays, imageview

I have a working app where images are being downloaded from the server, stored locally and being displayed in an image view as a slideshow every few seconds. I would like to count how many times each images is being displayed. I'm unsure how to tackle this. Should I make 6 counters (one for each image) or should I create an array to store the image name and count? But how do I update it?

Any assistance or code snippets would be much appreciated.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imgholder);
        Timer mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // As timer is not a Main/UI thread need to do all UI task on runOnUiThread
                DashboardActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // increase your position so new image will show
                        position++;
                        // check whether position increased to length then set it to 0
                        // so it will show images in circuler
                        if (position >= 6)
                            position = 0;
                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), user.fullName + "-" + position + ".jpg");
                        imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                        Log.v("test", "Now Showing Image: " + imgUri.toString());

                        // Set Image
                        imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
                        counter++;
                        Log.v("test","Image: "+ position +" has appeared: " +counter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, DELAY_TIMER);
```

Comment: is the images from server fixed in number? will the number change? or are you refreshing the images from server?

Comment: images number is fixed. 6 images will be downloaded. images might change from the server but they will always be 6.

Comment: does each images have unique id?

Comment: you should have something like that to differentiate each images

Comment: @Antonio yes each image has unique ID. images are named 0-5.

Comment: how are you passing the images for slide show?

Comment: Updated my question with my code for loading images into imageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an integer array of length 6 `int[] counters = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0}`, Then after `if(position >= 6) position = 0;` in your code , increment the counter as `counters[position]++;`. So you can always track the count of image at certain position from the array `counters`

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a HashMap to store the count

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
```

now whenever you set an image call below method:

```
private void updateDisplayCount(File file) {
 if(countMap.containsKey(file.getName())) {
   countMap.put(file.getName(), countMap.get(file.getName()) + 1);
 } else {
   countMap.put(file.getName(), 1);
 }
}
```

The following code will return the display count

```
int count = countMap.get(file.getName())
```

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out and get back to you

Comment: This answer also is correct. its a neater and way to do it. but for my usage, the other answer was simpler. if you have variable number of images use Hashmap. if you images are fixed you can go for the simpler solution provided below

Comment: @SaeedJoul please upvote if you find it useful. Thank you.